# Bipartite network error

Tags: r, bipartite, sna

I'm trying to analyse a bipartite network using the R bipartite package. I imported a csv file and converted it to a one mode network. Here's my code:

```
library(igraph) 
library(bipartite) 
g <- as.network(data)  
net <- as.one.mode(g, fill = 0, project="full", weighted=TRUE) 
summary(net) 
vcount(net) 
ecount(net)
```

But, when I try to calculate network metrics using the following command, it gives me an error.

```
betweenness_w(net, directed=NULL, alpha=1)
```

Here's the error message.

```
Error in if (NC == 2) net <- data.frame(tmp[, 1], tmp[, 2]) : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I appreciate some help

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data

Answer (score 0):

You could be confusing `igraph` graph objects with matrices.

For example I can replicate your error by feeding a graph object to the `betweeness_w` function:

```
> g=make_full_graph(5)
> ecount(g)
[1] 10
> betweenness_w(g)
Error in if (NC == 2) net <- data.frame(tmp[, 1], tmp[, 2]) : 
  argument is of length zero
```

But `betweenness_w` wants a weighted edge list. See the documentation.

Of course this is speculation because you've not given us a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is very helpful. Could you tell me how to create a weighted edgelist from a csv file that has two columns (representing the two types of nodes)?

Comment: you should edit your question to clarify thats what you are trying to do, and include a sample of your CSV file and any other data. If you can't edit this question, start a new one.